# Visual Stuido Installation path folder name modified

Tags: visual-studio, directory, installation-path

I was trying to organize my working folders cleanly and neat. And there I've got my visual studio 2017 installed in a location, say `Path\To\VS`. I forgot when I renamed one of the folders which it has VS 2017 in it, say `Path\To\VS` changed to `Path\To_the\VS`. I did intentionally rename the folder due to some requirement on other projects, hence I don't want to rename it back.

I tried to check and locate the VS folder with Visual Studio installer, but the VS installer doesn't allow me to change the installation path. The worst case is probably I have to re-install back. Are there any other options for me to retrieve back?

Comment: Is it really a good reason to rename the folder? Can you keep the VS install dir as is and create a new folder according to the requirement of other projects? Renaming the VS folder may break something that you won’t instantly notice, but still bite you after a long time. It should be leave unchanged.

Comment: That path I changed is like the root of all my projects. Actually you're right, that was so crucial. But, the reason I changed is that the folder path name actually contains " " (space) character, that's my mistake for the first I created the folder (you know 'newb'). and that mistake could lead to an installation issue on further other projects.